# Explain why $\varphi$ is a tautology, and $\psi$ is a contradiction (unsatisfiable formula)

Tags: logic

Let $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ be a contradiction with well-formed formulas $\varphi$ and $\psi$. Explain why $\varphi$ is a tautology and $\psi$ is a contradiction (unsatisfiable formula).

We have begun propositional logic in class and this is an example for lecture. I am confused how to prove this seeing as it doesn't seem plausible to use truth tables.
I was thinking of proving this by contradiction or by substitution, however I am also unsure how to get this started.

Comment: A contradiction is always false. If $\phi$ is false then $\phi\to\psi$ would be true. Since it is always false, $\phi$ must always be true and is, therefore, a tautology.

Comment: @JohnDouma many thanks, it seems I was over complicating this. Your explanation is clear and easy to grasp!

Answer (score 1):

You know that for a formula  to be a tautology it must be true under every interpretation (or be assigned the value of true in ever structure, depending on how it is defined in your course). Contradiction is defined analogously. Looking at the truth table for the implication arrow, we know that for  →  to be a false,  needs to be true and  needs to be false.

Hence for  →  to be a contradiction,  needs to be true in all interpretations (a tautology) and  needs to be false in all interpretations (a contradiction).